Riverpod generator and generating util classes
I'm trying to work with Riverpod, specifically with riverpod_generator and since there is not a lot of documentation surrounding this, I'm having trouble setting up a project to make use of all of this. I want to create a provider with the shared_preferences package so I can access this provider globally. It's seems by using this generator you can avoid to know which provider you need (state, future, etc.) which is neat thing I must say but I'm not quite sure I understand the whole scope yet.
First the class that will be the global shared pref provider (although this is not set up correctly, hence the ask for help)
@riverpod // annotation for the riverpod_generator
class SharePrefNotifier extends _$SharePrefNotifier{
  @override
  SharedPreferences build() {
    return _sharedPreferences;
  }

  // Obtain shared preferences but this is not correct although the compiler asks to be late
  late SharedPreferences _sharedPreferences;

  int? get getPin =>
      _sharedPreferences.getInt(_pinKey);

  Future<void> setPin(int? pinNumber) async => await _sharedPreferences.setInt(_pinKey, pinNumber);
   
  
  Future<void> removePin() async => await _sharedPreferences.remove(_pinKey);
   
  

  Future<void> deleteAll() async => await _sharedPreferences.clear();
}

When I fix the setup for shared pref provider, I want to access it in another provider:

@riverpod
class SettiingPinNotifier extends _$SettiingPinNotifier {
// referencing the shared_pred notifier on the top of the scope if possible so I can reference it anywhere in this provider if I have multiple methods
  final sharedPrefProvider = ref.read(sharedPrefProvider.notifer);
  @override
  SomeDataState build() {

    return const SomeDataState();
  }


  void setUpAPin(int? number) {
      sharedPrefProvider.setPin(number); // referencing the shared pref provider and setup a pin number
    state = state.copyWith(pin: number); // adding it to the state so I can change the UI accordingly 
  }


}

What is the best approach here BUT using the said riverpod_generator/riverpod_annotation? Thanks in advance for your help.

We don't have an actual instance of SharedPreferences, and we can't get one except asynchronously, thus creating the following dummy provider.
@riverpod
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences(ref) {
  throw UnimplementedError();
}

After that in the main.dart
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return runApp(
    ProviderScope(
      overrides: [
        // Override the unimplemented provider with the value gotten from the plugin
        sharedPreferencesProvider.overrideWithValue(prefs),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),

);
And finally create a service that deals with the SharedPreferences instance, and a provider for it.
@riverpod
SharedPreferencesService sharedPreferencesService(SharedPreferencesServiceRef ref) {
  final sharedPreferences = ref.watch(sharedPreferencesProvider);

  return SharedPreferencesService(sharedPreferences);
}

class SharedPreferencesService {
  SharedPreferencesService(this.sharedPreferences);

  final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

  Future<void> setPin(int? pinNumber) async => await sharedPreferences.setInt(_pinKey, pinNumber);
  // add all methods, getters, and etc.
}


Thanks for the answer mate, it worked. But a question if you don't mind, in this case, is it better just to make a service class with SharedPref i.e. (class Storage { final SharedPreferences _sharedPref Storage(this_sharedPref)}) and just call that service class anywhere in the project? And if you generate class based providers, how to reference a class from the inside of that provider? something like you do with BloC and use a dependency injector and just getIt()? Thanks again

@GrandMagus , Don't mention it mate, you can use the Storage class directly, but then you will be responsible for providing the shared preferences instance.
If I'm understanding your question, please check the following link

I don't know if this is too late but let me leave this here:
You can define your provider like so:
late SharedPreferences sharedPrefs

@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
SharedPreferences prefs(PrefsRef ref) => sharedPrefs;

In your main.dart dart file, your can initialize the provider like so:
Future<void> main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

// Initialize Shared Preferences


sharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

runApp(
    const ProviderScope(
        child: MainApp(),
        ),
    );
}

You can then use the provider throughout your application like so:
ref.read(sharedPrefsProvider);

Additionally, you can also define a utility provider to make use of the shared preferences much easily. Check the example below:
class PrefUtils {
  /// Sets data in a json encoded string format to shared preferences
  /// using the given key
  Future<void> setStringData({required String key, Object? value}) async {
    if (value == null) {
      await sharedPrefs.remove(key);
      return;
    }
    await sharedPrefs.setString(key, jsonEncode(value));
  }

  /// Sets data of boolean type to shared preferences using the given key
  Future<void> setBoolData({required String key, required bool value}) async {
    await sharedPrefs.setBool(key, value);
  }

  /// Gets data of boolean type from shared preferences using the given key
  bool getBoolData(String key) {
    return sharedPrefs.getBool(key) ?? false;
  }

  /// Gets data of any type from the shared preferences using the given key
  Object? getPrefsData(String key) {
    return sharedPrefs.get(key);
  }

  /// Clears all shared preferences data
  void clearPrefsData() async {
    sharedPrefs.clear();
  }
}

@riverpod
PrefUtils prefUtils(PrefUtilsRef ref) => PrefUtils();

I hope this helps. Happy coding.
